# Abstracting Common Behavior with Traits in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I have a trait that does the following:

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  def doSomething(elems: Seq[T])
}
```

I then have a factory that would create instances of the implementations of this trait:

```
object MyTrait {
  def apply(): MyTrait = {
    new StringTrait()
  }
}
```

Now the concrete implementation looks like this:

```
class StringTrait extends MyTrait[String] {
  def doSomething(elems: Seq[String]) = {
    // some generic logic here
    // some specific logic here (this code bit depends on the type of implementation)
    // some generic logic here 
  }
}
```

How could I now make StringTrait such that I pass in specific behavior from it and having the generic logic defined in a abstract class? One way would be to pass in the behavior as a thunk, but that wold mean that I have to modify my doSomething(...) method to take an additional parameter which I would prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options, for the sake of illustration I'll assume that the type specific behaviour is a Seq[T] => T (i.e. you take a Sequence of T and produce a T as a result):

Inheritance based:

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
  def doTypeSpecificStuff(a: Seq[T]): T

  def doSomething(elems: Seq[T]): T = {
    // generic code stuff
    val t: T = doTypeSpecificStuff(elems)
    // more generic code
    t
  }
}

class StringTrait extends MyTrait[String] {
  def doTypeSpecificStuff(elems: Seq[String]) = {
    elems.reduceOption(_ + _).getOrElse("")
  }
}

def client(thing: MyTrait[String], elems: Seq[String]) {
  thing.doSomething(elems)
}
```

Type class:

```
trait MyTypeClass[T] {
  def doTypeSpecificStuff(a: Seq[T]): T
}

object StringTypeClass {
  implicit val instance: StringTypeClass = new StringTypeClass()
}

class StringTypeClass extends MyTypeClass[String] {
  def doTypeSpecificStuff(elems: Seq[String]): String = {
    elems.reduceOption(_ + _).getOrElse("")
  }
}

object TypeClassDependentBehaviour {
  def doSomething[T](elems: Seq[T])(implicit tp: MyTypeClass[T]): T ={
    //some code
    val stuff: T = tp.doTypeSpecificStuff(elems)
    //more generic code
    stuff
  }
}

def client(elems: Seq[String]) {
  TypeClassDependentBehaviour.doSomething(elems)
}
```